# How can I keep Blender from duplicating LODs when I copy/paste objects that have LODs?

Tags: game-engine

I'm going to have a lot of small obects in a scene. Luckily, they are all uniform, so I can just copy/paste the object. However, I have an LOD loaded on the first object and I've found that as you copy/paste this object, it also creates a new LOD object. So if my LOD on my cool object was "Cool project LOD," as soon as I copy and pasted that object it would create "Cool project LOD.001." I would have to manually go in and change all of the 100_ objects back to having the same LOD. Is there a way to avoid this and make it so that when an object is copy and pasted, it doesn't create a new LOD?

Comment: Use Shift+D to duplicate the original object instead of copy/paste (Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Blender, if you want to have multiple copies of same object, you may use the Array modifier and can have as much copies as you like.

Or you may Use the duplicate function, Using menu **Object -> Duplicate Object** or use a short key Shift + D to duplicate it

Best of luck :)

Comment: Shift + D did the trick! Thank you! I'll try an array, but the arrangement of the items is somewhat irregular, so we'll see. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I am glad it worked, have a nice time :)